# How to align references when styling Html css nav?

Tags: html, css

I am styling my own nav and I need to place About and Actions aligned to the left. But telephone, username, and cash were aligned to the right. How can I achieve this?

```css
.header {
 margin: 0;
 text-align: left;
 color: white;
}
.my-header{
 background-color: #003399;
}
.header li, form { display: inline;  }

.header-normal li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 14pt;
 font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
}
.normal li a:hover{
 color: #ff6699;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu_laba3.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="my-header">
  <ul class="header-normal header">
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Actions</a></li>
   <li> Telephone: +375293326369 </li>
    <li><a href="#"> username </a> </li>
    <li> 500$ </li>
   
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `float` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(slightly edited)

Add this to your CSS:

```
.header-normal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  }
ul.header-normal li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
  }
```

It treats the menu `ul` as a flex container, aligning the items vertically to the baseline. `margin-left: auto` on the third list item will cause everything from there on to be aligned to the right.

```css
.header {
 margin: 0;
 text-align: left;
 color: white;
}
.header-normal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  }
ul.header-normal li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
  }
  
.my-header{
 background-color: #003399;
}
.header li, form { display: inline;  }

.header-normal li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 14pt;
 font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
}
.normal li a:hover{
 color: #ff6699;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu_laba3.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="my-header">
  <ul class="header-normal header">
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Actions</a></li>
   <li> Telephone: +375293326369 </li>
   <li><a href="#"> username </a> </li>
   <li> 500$ </li>
   
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making two different classes one for About and Actions and then another for the rest. I also, adjusted some of the CSS so your nav elements would be vertically centered as well (line height and nav height).

```css
.header {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0px;
   color: white;
}
.my-header{
   background-color: #003399;
   height: 25px;
}
.header li, form { display: inline;  }

.header li {
   line-height: 25px;
}

.header-normal li a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   line-height: 25px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 5px;
   font-size: 14pt;
   font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
}

.normal li a:hover{
   color: #ff6699;
}

    .AlignLeft {
       text-align: left;
       float: left;
    }

    .AlignRight {
       text-align: right;
       float:right;
    }
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
    <body>
     <div class="my-header">
      <ul class="header-normal header">
        <li><a href="#" class="AlignLeft">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="AlignLeft">Actions</a></li>
         <li class="AlignRight"> Telephone: +375293326369 </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="AlignRight"> username </a> </li>
         <li class="AlignRight"> 500$ </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </body>
  <html>
```